# Pronunciation of "Syncing"?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, american-accent

I just realized that I have been reading this word since long ago, but I am not sure of its correct pronunciation in American and British English.

Comment: Its pronounced like sync•ing or synch•ing (ˈsɪŋ kɪŋ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pronounced the same way as 'sinking'. I'm interested to know how you thought it might be pronounced.

Comment: Maybe something weird like "Saincing" or "Sinsing". I was not sure It might be some word like gauge, which is pronounced like "gay-sh", and not "gaush"

Comment: @JosueGalindo It's much easier to think of gauge as *cage*, but with a g ! The way you said makes me worry you are emphasizing the -sh part

Comment: @JosueGalindo: please see my new answer. The things that I want to say are too long for this comment box.

Answer (score 0):

[Pronunciation of Syncing at howjay](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=syncing&submit=Submit)

You could also check a dictionary that includes both American and British pronunciations, such as [Longman's](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sync_2), although that gives you the pronunciation only for the base word, sync.

Even so, checking a dictionary and even asking at a website like here will provide only how some people pronounce any given words, with many words having quite different "received (standard) pronunciations."

Comment: As an Australian, I am regularly exposed to various British and North American pronunciations via teaching colleagues, movies, television, and a wide variety of ESL accents from my students and some colleagues. If I am aware of any variation in pronunciation, I will say so. As far as I am aware, there is no variation in the pronunciation of this word, and the dictionary I checked before posting included only this pronunciation.

Comment: @SydneyAustraliaESLTeacher Only a pronunciation dictionary, whose sole purpose is to provide regional and other varying pronunciations (BrE vs AmE, for instance) could begin to be comprehensive. While, there may be no difference in how Englishspeakers pronounce "in" or "ing" in this word, I wouldn't bet my life on it.

Comment: *In this case*, I would! (Some people may say '-ingk', but that is minor and predictable from their dialect.)